# Where am I wrong during create React nativ app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, npx

I run the command "npm install -g expo-cli" and I got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGb64.png)

"npm audit fix" and "npm audit fix --force" didn't solve the issue.

VS Code terminal doesn't recognize the "expo init NewProject" command:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa9Lt.png)

"npx create-expo-app NewProject" command also didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The security issues are irrelevant, Use `npx expo init` or add the relevant executables to your path.

Comment: Hi Eper, thank you for your question. I think it is a good question, but to help others in the future find your question via search, please add the relevant text in your images to your question - it is best to avoid links and images!